# how to register ajax control toolkit in GAC

Tags: asp.net, ajax, gac

I want to install ajax control toolkit in GAC in visual studio 2008. How to do that.

Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

First make sure that the ajax control toolkit is strongly named. This is mandatory if you want to install it in GAC. Then use [gacutil](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ex0ss12c%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) to install it in GAC. You can create a postbuild event if you want to run it from Visual Studio.